# WordPress | Accept incoming url with variable parameters

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I would like WordPress to handle an incoming url with a variable parameter and not throw a 404. Basically, an incoming url could look like this:

```
http://mysite.com/custom-post-type/some-post/?promo=12er34
```

I then pass that last segment into a signup form for promotions. Obviously, hitting this url directly would throw a 404.

Is there anyway to setup a conditional in my custom post type that would allow a match if the incoming url has an additional specified segment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom post-type template, you could do this:

`$code = isset( $_GET[ 'promo' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'promo' ] ) : '';`

By the way, the parameter in your url should have a `?` before `promo`.

Like this: `http://mysite.com/custom-post-type/some-post/?promo=12er34`

**Update:**

If you want to get this value regardless of whether you're on a custom post-type or the default post-type, try this in your `functions.php`:

```
function get_promo_code( $wp ) {
    if( ! is_single() )
        return;

    // Do whatever you want with the promo code here.
    $code = isset( $_GET[ 'promo' ] ) ? sanitize_text_field( $_GET[ 'promo' ] ) : '';
}

add_action( 'wp', 'get_promo_code' );
```

Comment: The more I think about this the more I think it would make sense to make this global. In other words, I don't want to limit this to custom post types. I'd like to match/allow incoming urls with /?promo=12er34 no matter what the post or page url is. Maybe this is a .htaccess thing?

Comment: I've updated my answer to illustrate how to catch the promo code for default post-types, as well as custom post-types.

Comment: Thanks Spencer, you know what though...I'm an idiot for not even trying this but without the above function, if I slap a string onto the end of my wp url like custom-post-type/?promo=125234 it works fine :/ I guess if it's a query parameter it doesn't throw a 404...? Weird, I just assumed wp would throw a 404 without even trying it. Am I missing something here?

Comment: It won't throw a 404 if the uri is valid. Appending a query variable like `?promo=123` has no affect on the uri itself, in this case. :) Also, the function I gave you only gets the query variable it doesn't allow it to not throw a 404.

Comment: Right. It's all so clear now...crap. Sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Awesome. I'm glad it makes sense now. Can you mark the answer as correct then? :)