# Wordpress : Module with the GET/POST value accept?

Tags: wordpress, api, post, module, arguments

In Wordpress, how to make a API like Module, which can accept the data being passed via POST arguments. I mean, the Wordpress should be able to accept the URL calls from external, and then process it.

I mean, as the external Application or myself manually, when i call:

- http://www.wordpress-site.com/test?name=james&age=14

Then how to write a module to read such incoming POST values and process it (Save them into the Database or something)

It is actually a public API.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one:

In Base page it should seems something like this :

```
<a href="http://yourlink.com&name=value$age=value">Click Here</a>
```

In Destination page it should seems something like this :

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['name']) && isset($_GET['age'])){ 
    echo "name=".$_GET['name'];
    echo "age=".$_GET['age'];
 }
 ?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hello, please i am talking about Wordpress. Not simple PHP. Thanks.

Comment: your grace, i am also know that, but this is d only way with respect to your requirement, so PHP code also will work in your WORDPRESS script.

Comment: or if you still want to use wordpress;s function then try with this one  <?php get_query_var( $var ) ?>

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [WordPress | Accept incoming url with variable parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099821/wordpress-accept-incoming-url-with-variable-parameters)

that helps you to get the incoming parameters and `wp` action hook might be helpful that you want to achieve.

[wp action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp)